# How to get the last git commit hash at build time?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When building my image in the CI/CD pipeline, I would like to retrieve the hash of the commit currently used for the build. I was hoping that the following Dockerfile would work:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk -X http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev make jo git
RUN pip3 install pyyaml logbook multiping dnspython requests paho-mqtt arrow paramiko click
WORKDIR /app
COPY config-prod.yaml ./config.yaml
COPY homemonitor.py .
RUN jo date=$(date -Iseconds) git=$(git rev-parse HEAD) > docker-build.json
CMD python3 homemonitor.py
```

The retrieval is in the last `RUN` line but I get an error:

```
Step 9/10 : RUN jo date=$(date -Iseconds) git=$(git rev-parse HEAD) > docker-build.json
168  ---> Running in 96b09729f8b6
169 fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
170 Removing intermediate container 96b09729f8b6
171  ---> 2aff5909f75d
```

My understanding of this error is that what I work on is not actually a `git` repository, but an export of the `HEAD`, and therefore there is no `.git` forlder holding commit information.

If this is the reason - **is there a way to retrieve the hash of the current commit, used for the build?** This is the one visible right at the start of the job (namely `d4c8af29`):

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.5.0 (577f813d)
  on srv zN2MsS9q
(...)
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/zN2MsS9q/0/wsw70-docker/homemonitor/.git/
From https://gitlab.com/wsw70-docker/homemonitor
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/102404788 -> refs/pipelines/102404788
   a1b4313..d4c8af2  master                   -> origin/master
Checking out d4c8af29 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
```

EDIT: my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` per request

```
all:
  script:
    - docker build -t ${PROJECT} -f Dockerfile .
    - docker tag ${PROJECT} registry.mydomain/${PROJECT}
    - docker push registry.mydomain/${PROJECT}
```

`PROJECT` is defined in the variables passed to CI/CD

Comment: Just curious: why do you need the commit when building the docker image, as opposed to during the pipeline in the container? You can get the commit sha when the pipeline is running with `$CI_COMMIT_SHA`.

Comment: @Adam: because I didn't know about the variables :) Thanks for the info. Now, I tried to use `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` (and `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`) but I got `None` as the result.

Comment: Are you using a self-hosted gitlab? and if so, what version are you on? Gitlab changed the name of a lot of the predefined variables a couple of versions ago. That might be the cause.

Comment: @Adam: I use gitlab.com with self-hosted runners. I checked the docs and the variable you pointed to is clearly documented, so I am at loss.

Comment: Could you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml`? or if not, explain how you're triggering the pipelines (tags, pushes, api triggers, etc.)?

Comment: @Adam: sure, it is extremely simple - I added it to the question as an edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204141/discussion-between-adam-and-woj).

Comment: Btw, I moved this to the chat to not clutter the comments to much. You can click the link above to get there.

Answer (score 2):

Inside my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I used `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` which returns the first 8 characters of the last commit's SHA. Worked for me as expected.

Use `CI_COMMIT_SHA` if you need all the digits of the SHA.

Here is the [list](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) of GitLab's predefined variables.

P.S. I used gitlab.com with its free runners.